# Using Visual Studio Code how can I jump to the next found item from the active editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I search something in Visual Studio Code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the result appears in the `SEARCH` pane. 
If I click or push <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an item, it will be opened in the editor window.

How can I jump to the next found item if the editor window is active, without using the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F4 and Shift-F4 will traverse your search results even if an editor window has focus.

If the search pane has focus the arrow keys will tab down to each found entry below the search widget and the file and location will be opened and highlighted as you go up and down.  If the folder is closed, the right arrow will open it.  And the left arrow will close it again.  It is pretty slick actually.

And Ctrl+Shift+F gives focus back to the search pane and you can scroll through your old results (with the arrow keys or F4) even if another term was selected and populates the search input - as long as you don't hit enter - which would perform the new search.

Comment: Thank you! So I could find the the name of it: `Focus Next Search Result`